# Bad request response is returned by AWS Lambda spring boot app having other request parameters with multipart/form-data parameter

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I have a simple spring boot endpoint to accept multipart/form-data parameter and a couple of strings.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public GenericResponse requestsByUpload(@RequestParam String reason, @RequestParam String userid, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {

    log.error("reason : {}", reason);
    log.error("userID : {}", userid);
    log.error("file : {}", file);

    GenericResponse response;
    response = invoiceService.byUploadFile(file, reason, userid);

    return response;
}
```

Once it is deployed to AWS Lambda it returns a bad request response. Without event getting entered to method body as no logs of the parameters are present.

But when the String params are not annotated with @RequestParam, request gets inside the method. File is captured as expected but String params become null. If I hardcode the String params for an instance, request gets success.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public GenericResponse requestsByUpload(String reason, String userid, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {

    log.error("reason : {}", reason);
    log.error("userID : {}", userid);
    log.error("file : {}", file);

    GenericResponse response;
    response = invoiceService.byUploadFile(file, "reason", "userid");

    return response;
}
```

What could be the possible issue here? Will be really helpful if you could assist.

Comment: Can you share a sample url which is used to invoke the lambda? How are the parameters passed?